# kineticJS can't resize images within group

Tags: canvas, kineticjs, image-resizing

I am importing images into a group, but when I try and resize them later I get no response (resizing the group makes no difference to the images). The images are written in as follows:

```
var myBGgroup1 = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: Math.round((stage.getWidth()/12)*2),
    y: 0,
    id: 'BGimg1'
});         
//add image:
var imageObjBG1 = new Image();
imageObjBG1.onload = function() {
    var graphicBG1 = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        Image: imageObjBG1,
        width: bgW,
        height: bgH
    });
    myBGgroup1.add(graphicBG1);
};
//add image again, above it, for retiling:
var imageObjBG1b = new Image();
imageObjBG1b.onload = function() {
    var graphicBG1b = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: -bgH,
        Image: imageObjBG1b,
        width: bgW,
        height: bgH
    });
    myBGgroup1.add(graphicBG1b);
};
imageObjBG1.src = imageObjBG1b.src = 'Content/images/buttons/canvas2_bgDots1.svg'
```

I have tried setWidth and setHeight and also tried setScale, referring either to 'graphicBG1' or 'imageObjBG1' - to no avail. Should I be using a path, e,g, 'myBGgroup1.graphicBG1' or something?

Comment: this code does not show where and how you resize. Surely the error is in the part of code where you try doing it. so add that code as well!

Answer (score 0):

**A typo in your code will prevent processing:**

```
image: imageObjBG1,    // Not capital "Image"
```

As @Ani says, you haven't provided enough code for us to help.

**A typical cause of the "nothing changes" symptom you describe:**

*You might have failed to do `layer.draw()` after you resized objects.*

In absence of more code by you, the example below creates and resizes KineticJS images.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/TedxV/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.0.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    var kImage1,kImage2;


    var group=new Kinetic.Group({
        x:0,
        y:0,
        id:"group1"
    });
    layer.add(group);


    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        kImage1=kImage(0,0,img);
        kImage2=kImage(0,-img.height,img);
        layer.draw();
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/BrickWall.jpg";


    function kImage(x,y,theImage){
        var image=new Kinetic.Image({
            x:x,
            y:y,
            image: theImage,
            width: theImage.width,
            height: theImage.height
        });
        group.add(image);
        return(image);
    }


    $("#smaller").click(function(){
        kImage1.setWidth(kImage1.getWidth()*.9);
        kImage1.setHeight(kImage1.getHeight()*.9); 
        layer.draw();  
    });
    $("#larger").click(function(){
        kImage1.setWidth(kImage1.getWidth()*1.1);
        kImage1.setHeight(kImage1.getHeight()*1.1); 
        layer.draw();  
    });


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <button id="smaller">Smaller</button>
    <button id="larger">Larger</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```